# Rewrite existing code with Java 8 Lambda

Tags: java

I have one object, two conditions and need to convert it into a list.

- `SelectItem` has `getLabel` and `getValue`
- Casting problem
- Expect Result -> List of Employees
- Object refer to class (Example: Employees.class)

The code looks like:

```
public static final List<Employees> onFilterObjectFromSelectItems(final String query,final List<SelectItem> selectItemList) {
  final List <Employees>result = new ArrayList<>();
  for (SelectItem sl : selectItemList) {
    Employees x = (Employees) sl.getValue();
    if (x.getCode.contains(query) || x.getName.contains(query)) {
      result.add(x);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: The Object type does not have getCode and getName() methods. Also, I suggest reading about generics in java and using them here.

Comment: exmaple > the object refer to firm.class, in class got entity 'private String name;
' and 'private String code;
'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a "(re)write code for me" service.

Comment: @BalusC: I agree it could be phrased a bit better, but I don't see anything wrong with someone saying, "I know how to do this the pre-Java 8 way, but need help converting my code to using streams/lambdas". Ryan, I recommend editing your question and making it a bit clearer.

Comment: Ryan: Stack Overflow is more effective if you show your attempt and tell the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
List<Employees> EmployeeList = selectItemList.stream()
    .filter(x-> x.getCode().contains(query) || x.getName().contains(query))
    .map(e->(Employees)e.getValue())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: FYI, SelectItem (List<SelectItem> selectItemList) is class and have 'getLabel()' -> type is String and 'getValue()' -> type is Object.     the getValue need to be casting first with Employees.how to cast inside java 8 and make it map (map(e->e.getValue())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());) ?

Comment: new SelectItem(Object value, String label)

Comment: Casting will be done as it was done before Java 8. I have updated the code for casting.